# What is the best-practice for using redux state inside components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, standards

Lets say I have a large store object, and I only need a small slice of it per component. what is the best practice for managing the state inside each component?

the two approaches i have considered, are either setting the internal component state to the slice of state that i need in componentDidMount(), or assigning a const to the slice in render(). what would be the benefit/drawback of each? they both update whenever something is changed, and all of my changeHandlers call actions on the store, instead of modifying component state directly. just to be very specific, i'm using mapStateToProps and only need to assign the slice to some internal variable because accessing the slice requires an object.map, and I only want to have to do that once per component, instead of every time i need to access the state (if i could just do this.props.storeName.someProp.value every time, i would)

setting to internal state

```
class LoginPrimaryCell extends Component {
  state = {
    data: this.props.storeFeatures.data.find(element => element.feature === 'login').settings
  }

 componentDidMount() {
     this.setState({ data: {...this.props.storeFeatures.data.find(element => element.feature === 'login').settings}})
  }

 handleChange = (event, name) => {
    this.props.editFeature({feature: 'login', setting:'checkbox', value: event.target.checked}) //editFeature is an action on store
  }

render() {
...rest of component...
```

assigning to a const

```
class LoginPrimaryCell extends Component {

 handleChange = (event, name) => {
    this.props.editFeature({feature: 'login', setting:'checkbox', value: event.target.checked}) //editFeature is an action on store
  }

render() {
 const data = {...this.props.storeFeatures.data.find(element => element.feature === 'login').settings}
}
```

All i'm looking for, is the best practice for this situation, and what the benefits/downsides are to each approach. alternatively, if there is virtually no difference, and it's all personal preference. Thanks!

Comment: feels like you might want to use memoized selectors in your `mapStateToProps`. e.g.: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Comment: looking up what this is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally the best place to filter/find elements would be to use a `memoized` selector in mapStateToProps instead of passing the entire data to component and filtering in it, unless you want to filter on a condition that is being set within state of the react component.

If however, there is a case that you want to filter within the component, it needs to be done within the render method using a memoized function since it will avoid computation if the same arguments are passed on consecutive renders and would not need handling of the props or filter change at any other location.

Setting the filtered data to state is not a very correct solution since you won't be updating this state often and also, you would need to update this state when your `storeFeatures` props or the filter condition change, which is all a bit cumbersome

Comment: very nice answer! i would just suggest adding one thing: if `mapStateToProps` returns a function then each component can have its own instance of selector dependant on that component props/state. ref: https://medium.com/@pearlmcphee/selectors-react-redux-reselect-9ab984688dd4 . also: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors

Comment: I completely agree with the memoized selectors approach for requesting the data from store, and will look into implementing this. for this question though, i'm more concerned with where to put the data once i've got it. i'm assuming with the memoized selectors, i could go back to just using this.props.selector.someVal? ideally, i would never be setting the internal component state directly, and changing any of the storeFeatures props triggers a re-render which auto updates either the state through componentDidMount in ex#1 or the const in ex#2

Comment: @Dsabadash from your components perspective, once selected in `mapStateToProps`, its just a regular prop. you shouldnt save it anywhere (unless you have a good case for using `getDerivedStateFromProps`)

Comment: perfect. i don't have any hard requirements to have to save the slice of state anywhere, it was just more of an issue of performing multiple filters on the store,
and wanting to perform these filters from within each component. since i had the filtered set, i had to save it somewhere. if i can return a filtered set from a memoized selector, then this solves my problem completely.

Comment: @Dsabadash yep, thats exactly what memoized selectors are for.